# PowerPoint content app crashes in PPT online sometime during a saveAsync call

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I have a PowerPoint content app that runs well in the desktop version of PowerPoint 2013 and 2016, but in PowerPoint Online it crashes (I believe) sometime during the execution of Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync() with this error:

[image]

I've traced it through this code:

```
var saveSelected = function (selected) {
    if (Office.context && Office.context.document) {
        Office.context.document.settings.set("selected", selected);
        Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
    }
    else {
        localStorage.setItem("selected", JSON.stringify(selected));
    }
}
```

and can see the code run through this block as well as pop out of it to the parent function and finish execution, but a moment later it crashes and on a reload the setting hasn't been saved, so I'm assuming the crash happens somewhere inside the asynchronous save. The data I'm trying to save is an object that looks something like this:

```
{
    siteUrl: "https://modtenant160315b.sharepoint.com",
    type: "chart",

    url:"/drives('b%21H9_EgioNdUWL9Etpw0KgzkCIo4W1XPBCt7YkrAyP0lx8OUvBlEQvQ52j2Fg2P-a0')/items('01DLGLVOTPCNS67WMCPBG22JL3VR4SOUWE')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0400-000000000000%7D%27)/charts(%27%7B00000000-0008-0000-0400-000002000000%7D%27)"
}
```

Any thoughts?

edit: I just added this to my app's landing page and it also causes the crash in PPT online, so it doesn't seem to take much:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("dummySetting", "this is my setting");
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function () {
    var x = Office.context.document.settings.get("dummySetting");
    $scope.sharepointUrl = x;
});
```

Comment: After set, and before saveAsync, can you get the value of "dummySetting"? I think the value should be in-memory. This does sound like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was due to an outdated Office.js file. Switching from a local version to a hosted copy resolved the crash.